# How to kill a single process on multiple workstations

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to write a .bat file that can look at clients that are in a file (hosts.txt) and see if calculator is running and kill it or them but it keeps say there are not instances found.

```
@echo off
cd \
for /F "tokens=1-2" %%a in ("hosts.txt") do (
wmic /node:%%a process where name='Calculator.exe' call terminate
)
```

What would be a better way of doing this or what am I missing?

Comment: The host name will be assigned to the variable `%%a`.  So you need to use that with the /NODE option in your WMIC command

Comment: You could also do this with the `TASKKILL` command inside the FOR.

Comment: Even with /NODE added I still get "call was unexpected at this time" I have looked into to and trouble shot but still get this error. Is more than just the batch file thats the problem?

Comment: Read the `WMIC` command usage, _clue: `WMIC /Node:@hosts.txt ...`_ (I also thought that the executable name was `calc.exe`) and you should use this syntax, `Where "Name='calc.exe'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment as an answer, *(one line only)*:

```bat
@WMIC /Node:@hosts.txt Process Where "Name='calc.exe'" Call Terminate
```

The answer assumes you have privileges to do so, you may need to include `/user:privilegedusername` and `/password:privilegeduserpassword`.

Comment: @KameronKujak, please mark the answer as accepted if it is your chosen solution. _You can do so by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer_.

Comment: thank you I'm new to this, I usually ask my teacher questions but he literally said he is as knowledgeable as us.

Comment: @KameronKujak, a good place to start is to read the help file for the command you are trying to use.  If you would have typed: `wmic /?` at a cmd prompt you may have noticed this: **/NODE                Servers the alias will operate against.**. Also you could have checked task manager or the System32 folder for the actual file name of Calculator.