# Script to Check for a Remote Process and “kill” it If Exists

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a script that will be executed on the 2K12R2 directory server and needs to

1. Check both of the Windows 10 workstations for a remote process (Calculator.exe) and kill/terminate the process if it exists.

a.  The script should use a for loop that reads in a text file called hosts.txt that contains the hostnames of the Windows 10 workstations

b.  The script should use tasklist and taskkill or a wmic query to enumerate the process (Calculator.exe) and kill it.

This is what I have so far but I'm unsure on how to do a for loop to check a text file for the host names.

echo off

tasklist /fi "imagename eq calculator.exe" |find ":" > nul

if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "calculator.exe"&exit

Comment: There are -many- examples all over the internet of using a `FOR` loop to read a text file. Use the command `FOR /?` for documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to kill a single process on multiple workstations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973196/how-to-kill-a-single-process-on-multiple-workstations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single line, *no `For` loop required*:

Using `WMIC`

```bat
@WMIC /Node:@hosts.txt Process Where "Name='calc.exe'" Call Terminate
```

*Depending upon privileges, you may need to include `/User:privilegedusername` and `/Password:privilegeduserpassword`.*

---

Or you could use a `For` loop and `TaskList`/`TaskKill`:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In (hosts.txt) Do @TaskList /S %%A|Find /I "calc.exe">Nul&&@TaskKill /S %%A calc.exe /F
```

You may need to use both the `/U` and `/P` options with both TaskList and TaskKill, *enter each command followed by `/?` at the prompt for usage information.*